# Unable to send email when exception is raised via smtplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, smtplib

I am wish to create a script that when encounters error sends me an email regarding the details of error.
But when I call the method in except block it doesnot I do not recieve any email. But if I write normally that is outside except block I recieve the mail. Can you please tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
import smtplib
from datetime import datetime
import traceback
def senderrormail(script, err, date, time, tb = 'none'):
    sender = "Aayush Lakkad <alakkad@smtp.mailtrap.io>"
    receiver = "Aayush Lakkad <alakkad@smtp.mailtrap.io>"

    message = f"""\
    Subject: Hi Mailtrap
    To: {receiver}
    From: {sender}

    This is an alert mail,\n your python script for {script}\n has run into an error {err} \n\n on date {date} \t time {time} with {tb}"""
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mailtrap.io', 2525) as server:
            server.login("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx")
            server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
            print('mail sent!')
    except:
        print('Mail not sent!')


now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
try:
    raise TypeError('ohh')
except Exception as e:
    t = traceback.print_exc()
    senderrormail('emailalert', e, date, time)
    print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an Google account for Developer. If you don't want change the security settings of the sending mail.There are two ways to start a secure connection with your email server:

1.Start an SMTP connection that is secured from the beginning using SMTP_SSL().
2.Start an unsecured SMTP connection that can then be encrypted using .starttls()

And I saw you have used

```
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mailtrap.io', 2525) as server
```

Just add the script you want to find the error in your directory and I reccomend you to do:

```
import smtplib, ssl
import sys
import filename #your script

def senderrormail(script, err, date, time, tb = 'none'):
    port = 465  
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "your_sending_email"
    receiver_email = "receiver_email"  
    password = "your password"

    message = f"""\
    Subject: Hi Mailtrap
    To: {receiver}
    From: {sender}

    This is an alert mail,\n your python script for {script}\n has run into an error {err} \n\n on date {date} \t time {time} with {tb}"""}

    context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
except:
    print("Mail not sent!")


now = datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")



try:
    t = traceback.print_exc(limit=None, file=filename, chain = True)
    senderrormail(fiename, t, date, time)
    print(t)    

except Exception as e:
    print("mail not sent")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If there is an error in the script, the code stops running at the `import filename` and prints out the error message in standard fashion. The rest of the code is therefore not run, and no email with the error details gets sent. Do you have any tips for circumventing this issue?